# Converting an existing instance of a class to a more concrete subclass

Tags: c#, inheritance

Situation:  I have a large shrink wrapped application that my company bought.  It is supposed to be extensible, yada, yada.  It has a DB, DAL and BLL in the form of SQL and DLLs.  It also has a MVC project (the extensible part) but 95% of the "Model" part is in the DAL/BLL libraries.

Problem:  I need to extend one of the "Models" located in the BLL.  It is an User object with 47 properties, 0 methods and no constructor.  What I started was a simple deivation of their class like:

```
public class ExtendedUser : BLL.DTO.User
{
    public bool IsSeller { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine if I just create a new ExtendedUser.  However, it is populated by another call into their BLL like:

```
BLL.DTO.User targetUser = UserClient.GetUserByID(User.Identity.Name, id);
```

I tried the straight forward brute force attempt, which of course throws a Cast Exception:

```
ExtendedUser targetUser = (ExtendedUser)UserClient.GetUserByID(User.Identity.Name, id);
```

I am drawing a complete blank on this very simple OO concept.  I don't want to write a Constructor that accepts the existing User object then copies each of the properties into my extended object.  I know there is a **right way** to do this.  Can someone slap me upside the head and tell me the obvious?

TIA

Comment: is the `User` class declared as `partial` by chance?

Comment: I don't have access to UserClient - it is in the BLL.  I could do it as an extension method but I am back to copying (or using AutoMapper) to transfer the User values to the ExtendedUser object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do want to use inheritance, then with 47 properties, something like Automapper might help you copy all the values across - http://automapper.codeplex.com/ - this would allow you to use:

```
// setup
Mapper.CreateMap<BLL.DTO.User, ExtendedUser>();

// use
ExtendedUser extended = Mapper.Map<BLL.DTO.User, ExtendedUser>(user);
```

Alternatively, you might be better off using aggregation instead of inheritance - e.g.

```
public class AggregatedUser
{
    public bool IsSeller { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public BLL.DTO.User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is a Model for MVC.  If I push User down all of the Views that depend on it break.

Comment: I think AutoMapper will probably be my fastest route.

Comment: I've only used AutoMapper once - but it did "just work" - which was great!

Answer (score 4):

What about this approach (basically Aggregation):

```cs
public sealed class ExtendedUser  
{
    public ExtendedUser(BLL.DTO.User legacyUser)
    {
        this.LegacyUser = legacyUser;
    }

    public BLL.DTO.User LegacyUser 
    { 
        get; 
        private set; 
    }
}
```

Comment: It will break my Model which the Views depend on.

Comment: @Keith Barrows: as far as I understand you can once refactor your Views to reffer to a User.LegacyUser instead of User for a legacy properties accessing and thats it, or you mean some other problems which may occur?

Comment: That would be a lot of refactoring to add 2 new properties.  :)

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to write a Constructor that accepts the existing User object then copies each of the properties into my extended object.

This is typically the "right" way to do this, unless you have compile time access to the BLL.  The problem is that a cast will never work- an `ExtendedUser` is a concrete type of `User`, but every `User` *is not an* `ExtendedUser`, which would be required for the cast to succeed.

You can handle this via aggregation (contain the instance of the `User` as a member), but not directly via inheritance.

This is often handled at compile time via Partial Classes.  If the BLL is setup to create the classes (ie: `User`) as a partial class, you can add your own logic into a separate file, which prevents this from being an issue.  This is common practice with many larger frameworks, ORMs, etc.

Comment: How can I tell if it was setup as a Partial class?  My hunch is it is NOT a Partial class.  I am finding so many instances of the application **almost** being OO then you can see where they did not understand something and turned it back into a Singleton pattern.  <bleh/>

Comment: @Keith: Look at the source code it generates.  If you don't have source, then it doesn't matter...

Comment: I can look at the MetaData and I can use Reflection on it - not a partial.  :(